# Find center of a side of a rectangular path

Tags: java, android

This is how my path looks:
[image]

As you can see it's a rectangle with curved edges and a notch. What I need to do is find the center of its width. I then want to create a segment from its center to another point. I have already tried to use PathMeasure, but it didn't work in my case for a number of reasons. I then found a way to find the center correctly:

```
        RectF bounds = new RectF();
        path.computeBounds(bounds, false);
        float centerX = bounds.centerX();
        float centerY = bounds.height();
        float anotherPointX = centerX + 100;
        float anotherPointY = centerY;
```

But I have no idea how to use these coordinates to get a segment as PathMeasure#getMeasure takes a start and an end, not coordinates!

Comment: I can't just draw it, I need to stick to the path. I need to use path Measure getSegment with coordinates

Comment: I have a point, an instance of the PointF class, what I want to do is create a path that has as start that point and as end another one that I already have as a constant. Now the problem is that I know for a fact that both points are part of the Path, so I tried to  convert my path to a PathMeasure and use getSegment to get the partial path that I need, but getSegment takes 2 floats, the distance from the Path's start to the new start and end of the partial path, but I only have PointF and I have no idea how to use it with getSegment